# MAC OS Big Sur issue with eclipse ide with opendjdk 8

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, java-8, macos-big-sur

I have recently upgraded my MACOS to BigSur. Earlier in catalina I was using Scala IDE, but after moving to BigSur that is not working at. Getting lot of exceptions on boot up, like null pointer exceptions.

Now I have moved to eclipse 2020-03, and am using openjdk-1.8.242, scala 2.11 version.
This eclipse works fine, but its not compiling scala code.

am getting below exceptions on boot up again:

An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Can someone help, am really struggling and blocked from my productivity.
Can we work on eclipse with java8 on MacOs bigSur? or should I revert back to Catalina

PFB the complete error trace:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=1.8.0_242
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/apugalia/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/Users/apugalia/eclipse-workspace/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/apugalia/.eclipse_keyring

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2021-08-03 14:47:51.960
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2021-08-03 14:47:53.612
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-08-03 14:47:55.104
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-08-03 14:47:55.104
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for COMMAND+SHIFT+T:
Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigate.open.type,Open Type,
        Open a type in a Java editor,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.navigate,Navigate,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@2dbc453a,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(COMMAND+SHIFT+T,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.lsp4e.symbolinworkspace,Go to Symbol in Workspace,
        ,
        Category(org.eclipse.lsp4e.category,Language Servers,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@106d4303,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2021-08-03 14:48:07.030
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.util.zip.CRC32.update(CRC32.java:74)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput.readBytes(ChecksumIndexInput.java:44)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput.readString(IndexInput.java:124)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfo.<init>(SegmentInfo.java:148)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:234)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:275)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:653)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:272)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1088)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:924)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.NexusIndexWriter.<init>(NexusIndexWriter.java:49)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.NexusIndexWriter.<init>(NexusIndexWriter.java:43)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.getIndexWriter(DefaultIndexingContext.java:425)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.storeDescriptor(DefaultIndexingContext.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.checkAndUpdateIndexDescriptor(DefaultIndexingContext.java:270)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.prepareIndex(DefaultIndexingContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.maven.index.context.DefaultIndexingContext.<init>(DefaultIndexingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.index.DefaultNexusIndexer.addIndexingContextForced(DefaultNexusIndexer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.createIndexingContext(NexusIndexManager.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.setIndexDetails(NexusIndexManager.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.index.nexus.NexusIndexManager.repositoryAdded(NexusIndexManager.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.repository.RepositoryRegistry.addRepository(RepositoryRegistry.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.repository.RepositoryRegistry.updateRegistry(RepositoryRegistry.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.repository.RepositoryRegistryUpdateJob.run(RepositoryRegistryUpdateJob.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:09.966
!MESSAGE The POM for me.lemire.integercompression:JavaFastPFOR:jar:0.1.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:23.689
!MESSAGE The POM for me.lemire.integercompression:JavaFastPFOR:jar:0.1.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:24.398
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:24.413
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:37.307
!MESSAGE File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:37.308
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:37.315
!MESSAGE Ignored reentrant call while viewer is busy. This is only logged once per viewer instance, but similar calls will still be ignored.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.checkBusy(ColumnViewer.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.update(ColumnViewer.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.update(CommonViewer.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.update(StructuredViewer.java:1976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.nested.NestedProjectsLabelProvider.lambda$2(NestedProjectsLabelProvider.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAccept(CompletableFuture.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniAccept.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:646)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1609)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1596)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:37.389
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2021-08-03 14:48:49.338
!MESSAGE File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that it is possible to work with Eclipse & Java 8 on Big Sur. This error must be about something else. Intel processor or M1? Google for eclipse log file location and report the complete error stack trace (currently the error message is very generic). Does Eclipse not even start?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: @greg-449  added the logs

Comment: @RetoHöhener yes eclipse is launching, its just am not able to compile my scala code.
Also on booting up eclipse am getting below popup
An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Looks like a maven problem. This can have any number of causes. Personally I would first try to compile the project from the terminal, to see if the problem is with Eclipse or with the Maven configuration. Do you know how to do that? `mvn -e -U clean compile`

Comment: so this project builds fine from terminal and also from eclipse. 
the issue is happening only with the scala code, its not compiling scala

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any experience with Scala. "the project builds" to me means that all Maven plugins run without error. What I can say based on your information is that if the scala code is not compiled when building from the terminal, your problem is unrelated to the Eclipse error.

Comment: somehow maven in eclipse is not able to compile scala code.
are aware of 'Lifecycle mapping' file in eclipse under maven we configure.

for me it is pointing to this -> /Users/anurag/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml
but am not able to find in my system. I suspect this could be the issue

Comment: Too many variables... The scala-maven-plugin is now on version 4.5.3. A well-behaved plugin should provide [eclipse lifecycle mapping](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html). The [Scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html) talk about some manual actions required in .classpath file. No idea if that information is up-to-date.

Comment: got the fix .. maven plug in eclipse required to be updated for scala